# Using a Try and Except block, but in the Except Part it says Not Defined Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My code is converting Fahrenheit to Celsius. This is it.

```
def again():
    calc = raw_input("Press y to convert again. Press n to quit. ").lower()
    if calc == "y":
        main()
    elif calc == "n":
        quit()
    else:
        again()

def main():
    fahrenheit = input("What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")
    try:
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) *5 / float(9) 
        print('%0.2F degree Celsius is equal to about %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))
        again()
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number")
        check()
```

If you run it, and type a letter instead of a number to convert. It doesn't execute the Except bit but says that letter is not defined. If I did
`fahrenheit = input("What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")`, how would I make the Try bit to turn the number which is in quotes into a normal number without the quotes? I think it is because I chose `Value Error` but I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to subtract an integer from a string when you execute `fahrenheit - 32`, which causes this exception:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

which isn't a `ValueError`, so it won't get caught by your `except` clause.

If you want to catch a `ValueError`, you need to put `fahrenheit = int(fahrenheit)` inside your `try:` block.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 2.x, not 3.x.  In python 2.x you need to use `raw_input`, not `input`.  So change this:

```
fahrenheit = input(
    "What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")
```

to this:

```
fahrenheit = raw_input(
    "What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")
```

**Run showing `input()` failing in python 2.7:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe test.py
What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    "What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

**Run showing `input()` working with python 3.5:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" test.py
What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:/Users/stephen/Documents/src/testcode/test.py", line 31, in main
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / float(9)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

**Run showing `raw_input()` working with python 2.7:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe test.py awk_data.txt
What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? d
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "C:/Users/stephen/Documents/src/testcode/test.py", line 31, in main
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / float(9)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input from user into an integer in try as follows:

```
fahrenheit = int(fahrenheit)
```

if you are using python 3.x, this should be your final code

```
def again():
calc = input("Press y to convert again. Press n to quit. ").lower()
if calc == "y":
    main()
elif calc == "n":
    quit()
else:
    again()

def main():
fahrenheit = input("What do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius? ")
try:
    fahrenheit = int(fahrenheit)
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) *5 / float(9) 
    print('%0.2F degree Celsius is equal to about %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))
    again()
except ValueError:
    print("That is not a number")
    #check()
main()
```

hope it helps

Comment: Your code will generate, but not catch a ValueError if passed a letter.

Comment: It does generate ValueError. I just check it.

Comment: Yes, it does, but not inside the `try`, so it won't get caught and print "That is not a number".